# Express.js - ASP.NET-like MVC Routing

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

I'm trying to setup an MVC architecture for Express. What I am trying to accomplish is a routing mechanism close to ASP.NET's. For example for the following route:

```
/users/detail/1
```

express should call a module under controllers directory named users.js. Within the users.js module is a function named detail. And within the function, I can simply get the request parameter to get the id of the user.

My idea is to extract the users and map it to a users.js file using a simple require statement. But how can I tell express to call details() function by simply extracting the action part of the route which is 'detail' in the above example. I can use eval() but I am hearing that it's not a safe thing to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are [already available libraries](http://vschart.com/compare/compoundjs/vs/tower-js/vs/flatiron/vs/asp-net-mvc-framework) for this. [CompoundJS](http://compoundjs.com/) and [TowerJS](http://towerjs.org/) are both fairly mature, but there are [certainly others](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9744798). If nothing else, you can use them to inspire your own implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In browser-side javascript, you can typically do the following

```
function a () { console.log('called a');
window['a']();    // called a
```

You can do similar in node by replacing `window` with `global` such as

```
function a () { console.log('called a');
global['a']();    // called a
```

However, if you are pulling this function in from another file, it will be little different. Let's assume that you have the following file `a_module.js`:

```
exports.a = function () { console.log('a called'); }
```

And then in you're main file, you can do the following:

```
var a_mod = require('./a_module.js');
a_mod['a']();      // a called
```